# What is the correct way to pass through generics in this instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a reusable table component and I have an optional render property that can take "any" type but I want to be specific and not use any

so I have this:

```
type Column<T> = {
  index: string
  render?: (arg?: T) => JSX.Element | string
}

type Columns = Column<T>[]
```

but the above line doesn't work as I'm not sure how to pass in the generic here?

then when I pass in the columns later like this:

```
const cols = [
  {
  index: "Phone Number",
  render: renderFunction('test'),
} as Column<string>
```

but how do I pass the generic to `type Columns = Column<T>[]` this line?

I can't pass it form Columns as it might be different for each Column

Comment: If it's different from one column to another, then it doesn't make sense to have the generic at the level of `Columns`, does it?

Comment: but then how does that when you pass it through?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unknown` there and use it like this:

```
type Columns = Column<unknown>[];

const columns: Columns = [{} as Column<string>, {} as Column<number>];
```

Comment: 'Column<Type[]>' is not assignable to type 'Column<unknown>'

Comment: Where is `Type` imported from and could you paste the line where this error is raised?